# Disabling a field works in IE but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jsp, firefox, javascript

I have an image which acts like a button. I want this button to be disabled once clicked.

```
<img alt="Edit" class='btnEdit' src="images/edit.png"/>
```

I invoke the edit() function when it is clicked.

```
$(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
```

I want this button to be disabled once clicked. I tried the following way of disabling it. This works in IE but not in Mozilla.

```
function Edit(){
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Note: That image tag will get `prepended` dynamically using `$.prepend()`

Comment: `disabled` is not an `IMG` property

Comment: how is this acting like a button. Does a function run after clicking it ? If yes, you may consider [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: You cannot disable an image. The fact IE lets you do it says more about their browser than anything else. You need to handle the disabled case manually, I'd suggest by adding a class which is read on  click to determine if the event is allowed to conitnue.

Comment: Or use an actual button, you have the image button, a button with a background image and an image within a button.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using input `type="image"`, Since there is no `disabled` property in `<img>` tag. Instead of that img as button you can use as below one.

```
<input type="image" alt="Edit" class='btnEdit' src="images/edit.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button not the image, whatever you are using maybe an anchor or something else

```
$("#YourButton").bind("click", Edit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabled is not an attribute of image.
You need to do it like this..

```
function Edit(){
     if($(this).attr('class').indexOf('disabled') == -1)
          $(this).addClass('disabled');    // similarly use $(this).removeClass('disabled'); once finished editing
}
```